# Как прервать цикл через значение из дата-атрибута?

Tags: jquery

Доброе время суток. Какое условие должно быть, чтобы прервать цикл на значение **3** из **data-rating**?

```js
$(function(){

  $(".rating__icon").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).attr('data-rating-icon', 'true');
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating" data-rating="3">
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала берете значение из `data-rating` атрибута, затем просто сравниваете индекс текущей итерации и значение из дата-атрибута, когда значение совпадает возвращаете `false`;

Если вернуть `true`, то перейдет к следующей итерации, как при использовании `continue` в нормальных циклах, если вернуть `false`, то цикл прервется, как при использовании `break`.

```js
(function(){
  const rating = $('.rating').data('rating');
  $(".rating__icon").each(function(index, elem) {
    index++;
    console.log(index);
    if (index === rating) {
       return false;
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating" data-rating="3">
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
    <svg class="rating__icon"></svg>
</div>
```